# How can I replace the broker.xml in ActiveMQ Artemis with a customized broker.xml while creating the docker image using dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mqtt, activemq-artemis, on-premises-instances

I am trying to implement SSL certificate in my ActiveMQ Artemis docker image in on-prem server. I have modified the `broker.xml` and `dockerfile` to implement the change in the image, but whenever I am trying to run the image, it is throwing me error:

```
CREATE_ARGUMENTS=--user username --password password --silent --require-login --http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia
broker already created, ignoring creation
Running sed command
sed: can't read /var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/artemis.profile: No such file or directory
```

Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /var/lib/artemis-instance
RUN mkdir -p /etc/certs/
RUN chmod 755 /var/lib/artemis-instance
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/broker.xml; ln -s artemis.profile /var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/artemis.profile
COPY broker.xml /var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/broker.xml
COPY ./docker-run.sh /
```

`broker.xml` (have changed only in acceptors):

```xml
            <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
            <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

            <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
            <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

            <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
            <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/var/lib/artemis-instance/etc/certs/;keyStorePassword=password;needClientAuth=true </acceptor>
        </acceptors>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found that is admittedly a bit janky is to copy the `broker.xml` to a different directory. Copy `/opt/docker-run.sh` outside of the container, edit the `docker-run.sh` with the following

```
if ! [ -f ./etc/broker.xml ]; then
    /opt/activemq-artemis/bin/artemis create ${CREATE_ARGUMENTS} .
else
    echo "broker already created, ignoring creation"
fi
cp ./broker.xml ./etc/broker.xml
exec ./bin/artemis "$@"
```

and add the new `docker-run.sh`to your `Dockerfile` to be copied over.

The reasoning is that artemis won't do anything if the `broker.xml` already exists where you try to copy. So you let artemis generate the `broker.xml`, then overwrite it with your new one, then start artemis.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/docker.html#overriding-files-in-etc-folder) and create `/var/lib/artemis-instance/etc-override`